# AWS Api Gateway not setting CORS on 204

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've built a frontend application with Angular which uses an API backend hosted on AWS ECS, provided by AWS Api Gateway.

So, this is my setup:

`/user/{userId}/account/{accountId}/dashboard/{proxy+}`
is the endpoint on API Gateway

it's using an AWS Lambda **proxy integration** for the `OPTIONS` method, which currently only checks if the origin is allowed or not to proceed

the `GET` method instead uses a custom AWS Lambda authorizer within the **Method Request** part, then it proceeds to the **Integration Request** part with a VPC Link to the ECS microservice and finally goes back to the **Method Response** part.

Currently possible HTTP status codes are: `200, 204, 401, 500, 504` and only `204 and 504` are set here (sincerly I don't know if it does something or not)

this is the Node.js Lambda authorizer relevant code:

```
const UNAUTHORIZED_STRING = "Unauthorized";
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    /* Preliminar checks here */

    const keyRequiresAuth = xApiKeyRequiresAuth(xApiKey);
    if (keyRequiresAuth) {
        // try validating using cookie
        // uses generatePolicy at the end
        userAuthentication(cookieValue, event, callback);
    } else {
        // Validate using x-api-key
        const generatedPolicy = generatePolicy(xApiKey, 'Allow', event.methodArn);
        callback(null, generatedPolicy);
    }
};

const generatePolicy = (principalId, policyEffect, resource) => {
    const authResponse = {
        principalId: principalId
    };
    if (policyEffect && resource) {
        authResponse.policyDocument = {
            Version: '2012-10-17',
            Statement: [{
                Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
                Effect: policyEffect,
                Resource: resource
            }]
        };
    }
    return authResponse;
};
```

Assuming that Microservices are not setting any headers at all, the problem is, while I made it with `401` and `504` status codes by setting them as a default gateway response, how do I manage to return CORS with `204`?

IMHO, I think API Gateway has the most complex system to set error responses, but, apart from that, I managed to let it return CORS with a **401 Unauthorized** error

**Update**

I made it with http status `500` aswell, but by setting a default Gateway response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after two days of testing I came out with a solution. I mean, probably I've misunderstood something inside AWS API Gateway, but I saw that my endpoint was actually referencing to a VPC Link which was pointing at my ECS microservice.

Only thing I had to do was update that microservice with CORS response headers,
that fixed this issue

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a proxy integration, setting CORS in API Gateway is not enough.  The response from Lambda has to include the headers.

> To enable CORS for the Lambda proxy integration, you must add Access-Control-Allow-Origin:domain-name to the output headers. domain-name can be * for any domain name.

source: [Set up Lambda proxy integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

Comment: pretty sure this is not true: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html > If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway automatically sends a response to preflight OPTIONS requests, even if there isn't an OPTIONS route configured for your API.

Comment: Perhaps something changed in the last 3 years.  The quote above is from the linked docs on AWS. ‍♂️